# How to upload a file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to upload and save a file in a folder called "uploads" in a root folder using the following route, but it cannot save anything, and I don't even get any error. I can't find the problem.

```
router.post("/tracker/:id/po", function(req,res){
 Tracker.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundTracker){
     if(err){
         console.log(err);
     }else{
            var user = req.user.id;
            var id = req.params.id;
            var fileName = 'C' + id + '.pdf';
            var storage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: function (req,file, callback){
                    callback(null, './uploads/'+ user + '/trackers');
                },

                filename: function (req, file, callback){
                    callback(null, fileName);
                }
            });

            var upload = multer ({storage : storage}).single("file");
            upload(req, res, function(err){
                    console.log(user);
                    res.redirect("/tracker/"+req.params.id+"/info");

            });

        }
 });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using fs module?

Comment: How can I use fs?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback